# how to use a xib file for all device sizes in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout, xib, size-classes

I would really appreciate if someone can tell me about how can I use one xib file to target different device sizes. I am creating a Custom Keyboard extension using a xib file having view property of "freedom". The view loads great in iPhone 4,4s,5 and 5s. However whenever i run the app for iPhone6 or 6s there is a blank space at the right hand side. (please see the attached screenshot, missing area is shown in red), looks like the keyboard doesn't stretch according to the screen size.

How can i fix that? I disabled the auto layout and use size classed option. I am a very new developer and coding using swift. 
Thanks a lot

[image: Keyboard should stretch up to Red area]

Answer (score 1):

I would use autolayout for this, I would not disable it in the xib. Its also the reason as to why you have a space at the end of your view, as it is not expanding automatically to the sides, it has been set statically e.g. setting the frame.

I would have a look at this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial) but in the mean time I would re-enable autolayout then with your keyboard view container ctrl click drag to your main view and select Leading(left), Trailing(right), Top & Bottom Space to Container. Below is the popup menu from ctrl clicking [image: constraints] then select the triangle at the bottom right [image] then Update Frames, this will relayout the view. It might not layout the keyboard keys correctly but its is a start.

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion, I tried it however since i am using a xib file (not a storyboard directory) and have 38 items in the xib file (alphabet letters) it is really hard to manage all constraints for all of them. Add missing constraints doesn't help either. When i use the custom layout types in particular it messes up the layout for other device types.